# about Java Generics, how to get the class

Tags: java

for example these is a ApiRes class

```
@Data
public class ApiRes<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1657033024659806411L;
    private boolean success;
    private T data;
    private String errorMsg;
```

we can get these class like that  `ApiRes.class`

but I want to get ApiRes class, how to get it, `ApiRes<UserInfo>.class` was wrong.

Comment: Why do you need it? I'm asking because this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Why is there no class literal for concrete parameterized types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ106)

> ***Because parameterized type has no exact runtime type representation.***
>
> A class literal denotes a `Class`
>   object that represents a given type.
>   For instance, the class literal
>   `String.class` denotes the `Class`
>   object that represents the type
>   `String` and is identical to the
>   `Class` object that is returned when
>   method `getClass` is invoked on a
>   `String` object. A class literal can
>   be used for runtime type checks and
>   for reflection.
>
> Parameterized types lose their type
>   arguments when they are translated to
>   byte code during compilation in a
>   process called type erasure . As a
>   side effect of type erasure, all 
>   instantiations of a generic type share
>   the same runtime representation,
>   namely that of the corresponding raw
>   type .  In other words, parameterized
>   types do not have type representation
>   of their own. Consequently, there is
>   no point in forming class literals
>   such as `List<String>.class` ,
>   `List<Long>.class` and `List<?>.class`
>   , since no such `Class` objects exist.
>   Only the raw type `List` has a `Class`
>   object that represents its runtime
>   type. It is referred to as
>   `List.class`.

Comment: Hmmm ... You answered a clear duplicate!